# install composer No package php-cli available

Tags: composer-php

i need to install composer in my server 
i have this 
No package php-cli available.
No package php-zip available.
Package wget-1.14-18.el7_6.1.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package unzip-6.0-20.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do

Comment: Explain your problem in a more clear way: show what you are trying to do and what exactly the error you are facing is

Comment: I am trying to install composer on my centos 7 server
now i find this error
[ErrorException]
  file_put_contents (./ composer.json): failed to open stream: Permission denie
  d

Comment: This is apparently a permission error. You need to use `sudo` with composer or change the files permission so that composer can write the file there